# Show inner absolute positioned div outside outer scrolling div

Tags: html, css

Here is a sample demo I created - https://jsfiddle.net/smitamore/jmbvy6re/4/.

```
.scroll-limit{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: scroll;
  background: #0066CC;
  color: white;
}

.fruit_list{
  position: absolute;
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: scroll;
  height: 100px;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 200px;
  top: 0;
  background: #CCFFE5;
  color: black;
  display: none;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

If you click any checkbox, the following column will show list of fruits in a scrolling div. I want to make sure this scrolling div is shown completely even if the outer scrolling div is smaller than inner scrolling div.

I would really appreciate if anyone can help me out with this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Change your function to

```
$('.show_fruits').change(function() {
if(this.checked) {
   $(this).closest('tr').find('.fruit_list').show();
   $(this).closest('tr').find('td.fruit_list_wrapper').css('position', 'absolute');
}else{
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.fruit_list').hide();
  $(this).closest('tr').find('td.fruit_list_wrapper').css('position', 'relative');
}
```

});

The element you want to show cannot have the property "position" setted to "relative", so you just change it to "absolute" when it appears and set again to "relative" when it must be hidded

You can also create another class, for example

```
.fruit_list_wrapper_visible{
  position: absolute!important;
}
```

and add a simple line to your function, like this

```
$('.show_fruits').change(function() {
    if(this.checked) {
       $(this).closest('tr').find('.fruit_list').show();       
    }else{
        $(this).closest('tr').find('.fruit_list').hide();
    }

    $(this).closest('tr').find('td.fruit_list_wrapper').toggleClass('fruit_list_wrapper_visible');
});
```

**EDIT** - 
As the author mentioned the only issue with this is that if you scroll the outer div, the inner fruit list stays at same position. To solve this just add **"z-index: 1;"** to the **"fruit_list_wrapper"** class.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick help. This works good. Only issue is that if I scroll the outer div, the inner fruit list stays at same position. Is there something that we can do about it, so that it will always start at the top of the corresponding row?

Comment: Oh.. you're righ, just add "z-index: 1;" to the "fruit_list_wrapper" class and this problem is solved :)

Comment: Even with the z-index, the issue exists. If you scroll the outer div, the list stays where it was originally displayed. All other elements move with the scroll. I updated my demo with the solution you provided.